# Not able to print properties with console.log in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I want to print Props passed in to my component `GroceryListItem` from parent component `GroceryList`

My Code of `GroceryList` :

```
    class GroceryList extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          groceries: [ { name: "Apples"}, {name: "Orange"}, {name : "Banana"} ]
        };
      }

    render() {
        const element = [];
        for(var index = 0; index < this.state.groceries.length; index++) {
           element.push(<ul><GroceryListItem grocery={this.state.groceries[index]} /></ul>);
        }

        return (
         <div>
           {element}
         </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Code of `GroceryListItem` :

```
class GroceryListItem extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

render() {
    // I want to print the props passed here, but below code is not printing it
    console.log("Hi from GroceryListItem " + this.props.grocery); 

    return (
        <li>
          {this.props.grocery}
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

The console prints :

> Hi from GroceryListItem [object Object]

The console shows `[object Object]` But not exact values like `Apples, Orange, Banana`. How can I print all values from `props`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the `name` property of your object

```
class GroceryListItem extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

render() {
    console.log("Hi from GroceryListItem " + this.props.grocery.name); 
    return (
        <li>
          {this.props.grocery.name}
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```